# Why isn't this jQuery loop not firing every time?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, each, cart

I have a page (product category in Woocommerce) with 12 products on it. Each product has a quantity field, and when you click a button at the bottom of the page, it loops over the products and adds any product to the cart with a quantity greater than zero:

```
$('.add-products').on('click', function() {
    $('.product-qty').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() > 0) {
            var pid = $(this).closest('.product-select').attr('product-id');
            var qty = $(this).val();
            add_to_cart(pid, qty);
        }   
    });
});
```

The add to cart function is like this:

```
function add_to_cart(product_id, qty) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {action : 'add_to_cart', 'product_id': product_id, 'qty': qty},
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(product_id + ": " + qty);
        }, error : function(response) {
            // throw error
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is if I set the quantity on a bunch of products, say four of them, it randomly adds some to the cart and not others. I tried making add_to_cart() asynch, I tried using setTimeouts() to give it time to run, but no matter what I do it never adds all the products with quantity > 0 to the cart. Inside of the add-to_cart() function it echos all of the products inside the success callback but they don't end up in the actual cart.

Is there a better way to do this?

I tried making add_to_cart() asynch, I tried using setTimeouts() to give it time to run. I looked through search results here and Google but haven't found an answer.

Comment: _"they don't end up in the actual cart"_... what does this mean? What / where is the _actual cart_? Sounds like a server-side problem because I don't see any issues with this code or what you say it logs

Comment: It the woocommerce cart. They log as having been added, but when I go to /cart only some of them are there, randomly, like the function is just firing a few times then stopping.

Comment: I'm going to try sending an array of products to PHP all at once and looping in PHP.

Comment: Phil I think you are right, PHP is synchronous so i think it was puking. I sent all the products to the cart as an array and looped in PHP, and it works.

Comment: PHP's individual request handling is single-threaded but your web server can send as many simultaneous requests as it is configured to handle. If your PHP code suffers from race conditions, then it should be improved. Once again, this has nothing to do with your client-side code. What if you have several different clients all adding to the cart at the same time?

Comment: While batch upload is the correct answer (see answer), an alternative is to use an *ajax queue* (various implementations exist on SO).  Then you don't DOS your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Looping ajax is not recommended.

ASSUMING you can change the server side processing you can instead do this:

```
$('.add-products').on('click', function() {
  const products = [];
   $('.product-qty').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
        var pid = $(this).closest('.product-select').attr('product-id');
        var qty = $(this).val();
        products.push({pid, qty});
    }   
  });
  if (products.length > 0) addToCart(products)
});
```

and change addToCarts to send the object to the server as a JSON string

Comment: Wouldn't this entirely depend on what format the server-side code expects? I feel this isn't a complete answer

Comment: @Phil It is his server. If not then of course my answer misses the server part. But seeing the comment OP wrote when I was writing this, they can change the server to accept whatever they need